# How do I get all the groups that have all the users I specified in an array in Rails/MongoId?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have a collection of `Groups`, a collection of `Users` and a collection of `GroupUsers` that contains 2 fields: `group_id` and `user_id`.
I would like to find all the groups that have all the users I specified in an array.

Example. If I do:

```
group1 << user1
group1 << user2
```

When I try to find the groups that contain `user1`, `user2` and `user3`, I should get no results. But if want the groups that contain `user1` and `user2`, I should get `group1`.

I tried:

```
GroupUser.where(:user.in => [user1, user3]).group_by(&:group)
```

But this returns `group1` because the `user1` is a member of this group.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `GroupUser.select(:group_id).where(user_id: [user1.id, user2.id, user3.id])`

Comment: I already tried and it doesn't work. It gives me each groups with one of this users.

Comment: Yes, for sure. 
`class Group
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name
  
  has_many :group_users
end

class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name

  has_many :group_users
end

class GroupUser
  include Mongoid::Document
  
  field :actived, type: Boolean, default: false

  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :user
end`

Answer (score 0):

We finally found a solution:

```
class Group
  embeds_many :users, class_name: "GroupUser"
  scope :with_status, -> (status) do
    where(:"users.status" => status )
  end
end

class User
end

class GroupUser
  embedded_in :group
  belongs_to :user
end
```

And then
`Group.where(:"users.user_id".all => [user1.id, user2.id])`

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score -1):

*(ActiveRecord only):* You can define this scope in your `Group` class, using `having` and `group` statements together:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :with_all_users, ->(users) do
    joins(:users)
    .where(users: {id: users.map(&:id)})
    .group('groups.id')
    .having('count(users.id) = ?', users.size)
  end
end
```

And then you can use it like this to get all the groups that have all the users you provide as an array or collection:

```
Group.with_all_users([user1, user2, user3])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But mongoid doesn't have a "joins" method.

Comment: Hmm I just saw the tags, I think you should clarify that on the question though!

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you just need to use `all` instead of `in`. See the first entry in the [selection doc](http://mongoid.org/en/origin/docs/selection.html).

> Queryable#all
>
> Add $all selection. Documents must match all values provided in the
>   array

```
queryable.all(field: [ 1, 2, 3 ])
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer but it's doesn't work. I don't know why. When i request with `user1` only, i have a result. Too, if i request with the `user2`, i have a good result too. But if i request with `user1` AND `user2`, i have no result. It's look like `all` acts like `in`

Comment: That means there is no `GroupUser` in the database that has both `user1` and `user2` associated with it. According to the documentation, `all` and `in` are opposites, `all` finds the documents that include all values in the array, `in` finds the documents that include any of the values in the array. I assume you're using a `has_many_and_belongs_to_many` here? What if you tried querying `Group.where(:users.all => [user1, user3])`, just a guess but probably won't work.

Comment: You're right, it's doesn't work too. I added now a has_many_and_belongs_to_many into my Group model, but i am not understand how it will help.

Comment: The GroupUser model contains a user status field, that is why i am not embedded it into Group.